# vshost32-clr2.exe has stopped working [Faulting module name: cdosys.dll, version: 6.6.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b774]

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I was running the application in visual c# 2010 express, the application ran for about 3 hours continuously in debug mode, after that it stoped working and shown a pop up saying
"
***[Window Title]
vshost32-clr2.exe
[Main Instruction]
vshost32-clr2.exe has stopped working
[Content]
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.***
"

i checked the application log.. so below is application log
***"Faulting application name: TestPro.vshost.exe, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba2084b
Faulting module name: cdosys.dll, version: 6.6.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7b774
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0005b8a5
Faulting process id: 0x2064
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd0273c31c2e76
Faulting application path: C:\work Copy\TestPro\TestPro\bin\Debug\TestPro.vshost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cdosys.dll
Report Id: 77537da3-6e81-11e1-b891-78e3b595863f"***

i couldnt able to identify the cause for this error, so somebody help me in finding the cause and fixing the issue..

Comment: as the above exception states "Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available." - just stay there and a popup with the answer will show.

Comment: CDOSYS is a COM server, it crashed on a buffer overflow.  Do strongly favor System.Net over CDO.  Make sure your anti-malware is in good shape.

Answer (score 2):

For this you can follow these steps-
1. Right Click on Project in Solution Explorer and Select Properties

1. Click on the Debug Tab if it’s not already selected.
2. Uncheck the Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process checkbox under the Enable Debuggers Section

Hope It will Work...

Comment: I think the problem was in app code and not in vshosts32-clr.exe. I don't think that disabling Hosting Process will fix the original issue here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your thread and visiting!

Please follow the steps below and check the symbol server settings in Visual Studio:

1. Go to Tools menu and Click Options
2. Expand Debugging node on the left panel Click General
3. Disable source server support on right panel
4. Disable .NET Framework source stepping

This happens because Visual Studio attempts to load symbol files for debugging but encounter a timeout issue sometimes.